# Oracle parallel query - How to find out actual number of spawned processes?

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing

I am using [Oracle parallel query](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_parallel_processing.html) feature on a 10G 3-node RAC where each node is a 16-CPU machine.
The question is, how can I see the **actual** number of Oracle processes spawned to execute the query on all 3 nodes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it in [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/05-may/o35dba.html):

First, find out the ID and serial# of the current session:

`SELECT paddr, sid, serial# FROM v$session WHERE audsid = userenv('sessionid')`

Then to see the parallel execution servers that are dedicated to that session:

`SELECT qcsid, qcserial#, SID, serial#, server#, degree`
`FROM gv$px_session pxs`
`WHERE pxs.qcsid = :your_sid AND pxs.qcserial# = :your_serial`